# I have a file which contains some data, want to save data in table format thru Bash script

Tags: bash, shell

Save data in table format.

File output data is like:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.X.X
MAC Address: 1C:xx:0D:ff:62:9A (Unknown)
Running: Linux 3.X|4.X
Nmap scan report for 192.168.X.X
MAC Address: 1C:xx:0D:88:59:F6 (Unknown)
Running: Linux 3.X|4.X
Nmap scan report for 192.168.X.X
MAC Address: 1C:aa:0D:2C:64:XX (Unknown)
Running: Linux 3.X|4.X
Nmap scan report for 192.168.X.X
MAC Address: 84:A9:3E:XX:1C:ss (Unknown)
Running: Linux 3.X|4.X
Nmap scan report for 192.168.X.X
MAC Address: cc:D5:5E:xx:6B:6B (Unknown)
Running: Linux 3.X|4.X
Nmap scan report for 192.168.X.X
MAC Address: xx:B6:xx:92:0C:1D (Unknown)
Running: Linux 3.X|4.X
```

But want to save data like (in table format):

```
--------------------------------------------
Nmap Scan Report for |    MAC Address     | Running
192.168.X.X          | xx:1B:xx:2C:xx:9A  | Linux 3.X|4.X
192.168.X.X          | 1C:1B:xx:2C:xx:xx  | Linux 3.X|4.X
192.168.X.X          | 1X.1G.7V.XX.xx.xx  | Linux 3.X|4.X`
```

Please help with the Bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for an `awk` script:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        print("Nmap Scan Report for |    MAC Address     | Running");
    }
    /^Nmap scan report for/ {
        ip=$5;
    }
    /^MAC Address:/ {
        mac=$3;
    }
    /^Running:/ {
        $1="";
        os=$0;
        printf("%-21s| %-19s|%s\n", ip, mac, os);
    }
    ' nmap-report.txt
```

Comment: But when I using your code found table format be like:

Comment: It shows Nmap Scan Report for | MAC Address | Running > in every line. I need this name as table name and data should be actual value as mention in above.

Comment: @Aniket : Then just modify the awk program accordingly, and make a new question on SO, if it does not work out.

Answer (score 0):

Perl version, using the little-known-these-days [format](https://perldoc.pl/perlform) feature (Which is granted probably overkill for something this simple when you can use `printf`, but I'm feeling fancy.)

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($ip, $mac, $host);

while (<>) {
  if (/^Nmap scan report for (.*)$/) {
    $ip = $1;
  } elsif (/^MAC Address: (.*)$/) {
    $mac = $1;
  } elsif (/^Running: (.*)$/) {
    $host = $1;
    write;
  } else {
    die "Malformed input.\n";
  }
}


format STDOUT_TOP =
--------------------------------------------
Nmap Scan Report for |    MAC Address     | Running
.

format STDOUT =
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< | @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< | @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<...
$ip,                   $mac,                $host
.
```

Example:

```
$ perl report.pl nmap.txt
--------------------------------------------
Nmap Scan Report for |    MAC Address     | Running
192.168.X.X          | 1C:xx:0D:ff:62:9A  | Linux 3.X|4.X
192.168.X.X          | 1C:xx:0D:88:59:F6  | Linux 3.X|4.X
192.168.X.X          | 1C:aa:0D:2C:64:XX  | Linux 3.X|4.X
192.168.X.X          | 84:A9:3E:XX:1C:ss  | Linux 3.X|4.X
192.168.X.X          | cc:D5:5E:xx:6B:6B  | Linux 3.X|4.X
192.168.X.X          | xx:B6:xx:92:0C:1D  | Linux 3.X|4.X
```